# SQLDateTime Overflow and All DateTime fields are Valid

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, linq

The exception message I receive is straightforward:

> SQLDateTime overflow must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 12:59:59 PM``

This is the VB 2013 code which uses Linq to SQL:

```
Dim BQCust = (
    From c In FinDB.Customers
    Where c.Customer_Account = 2000223).FirstOrDefault
FinDB.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict)
```

There were no changes made in this example.  I have manually checked all 6 of the datetime fields in the BQCust object of type Customer and none match the error condition.  All but 1 of them are flagged to allow Nulls.  The 1 that is not has a value of #5/14/2016 9:20:03 AM#.  Besides, wouldn't they all have to be valid to be included in the SQL DB table that I'm retrieving them from??  So what data is causing this exception?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [RecIdent] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Customer Account] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Customer Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Customer Status] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address 1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address 2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip Code] [char](10) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [Account Type] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Sales Representative] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Renewal Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Account Manager] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Acceptance Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Voided Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Expiration Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastChanged] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Customers_LastChanged]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: You may have to post a full code from retrieve from db, modification and transfer to db. It is possibility a datetime value is lost since the default .NET DateTime value is 0001/01/01 which is violated the SqlServer datetime minimum value.

Comment: Literally, to isolate the issue I just retrieved the data and immediately tried to submit it.  No changes were made between.  I used debug to view the Customer object.  Here are the values that I found: DateCreated: 11/1/1996, RenewalDate: 12/7/2015, VoidedDate: NULL, ExpirationDate: 12/7/2016 and LastChanged: 5/14/2016.

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that if you are having `VoidedDate = NULL (Nothing)` in the debugger, that means `0001-01-01` in .NET.

There is no null for DateTime object in .NET

If you would like to debug, try select data into a datatable and then update with the **exact same datatable**.

Comment: I find that hard to believe.  The table is defined to allow for NULL values and this code has been working for many months.  Most of the accounts have a null value in the VoidedDate field.  Why is this just now an issue?

Comment: FinDB is a DataContext used by Linq to SQL.  In the IDE, the VoidedDate property shows Nullable = True.

Comment: Any system/version upgrade? Any modification on the custom object class? Does this happen to all records or just one?

Comment: MSFT VS Community 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5; .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055.  So far, this account is the only one that has raised this issue.  It is possible that there are others but I still am not satisfied that I know what is causing it.

Comment: Project also references System.Data.Linq version 4.0.0.0.

Comment: What if checking all datetime value `if (VoidedDate == DateTime.MinValue) Insert(DBNull);` ?

Comment: Just for jollies, I manuall set the VoidedDate value to a valid date and tried to submit it.  Save results.

Answer (score 0):

I found an astute observation in another [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065028/sqldatetime-overflow-when-inserting-value-with-datetime-now?rq=1) thread.

> SubmitChanges() applies every change since you last called
>   SubmitChanges() or created the context. You can determine what all
>   changes are involved by looking at db.GetChangeSet(). Any date/time
>   column on any affected object could be the cause - for instance, if
>   any datetime comes through with a default of DateTime.MinValue, it is
>   out of range for SQL Server. – mellamokb Apr 17 '13 at 16:11

This is my problem!!  I tried the submit before getting the new value for BQCust and still got the error.  I have never used the GetChangeSet method before but I will now.  Thanks for the help!